# How can I stop my "headerSticky" and "content" divs from overlapping?

Tags: css

I'm making a page that has three main components: a "headerSticky" header div, "sidenav" left navigation div, and "content" div.

The side navigation is fixed and does not move; but the content div should be scrollable on its own. However, the top of the content div is always overlapped by the header div.

Here is the CSS for the header:

```
#headerSticky{
position:fixed;
padding:6px;
width: 100%;}
```

and the content div:

```
#content {
padding-top: 100px;
float:right;
overflow: auto;
height: 90%; 
width: 840px;
padding: 0 20px 20px;}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: Screen shot of the page. There should be a title for the table at the top (with the "Condition" and "Condition Status" values) that says "Problems," but it is hidden beneath the header:

[alt text http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/477/screenshot20100510at611.png](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/477/screenshot20100510at611.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the position from your #headerSticky. If you position something absolute or fixed, any subsequent elements will act as though its not there (in this case creating an overlap). Also, I'm not sure, but I think some of your styles may not be valid.

I hope this helps in some way.

Comment: Unfortunately I need the header to stay in place while the content div scrolls by, so taking off the position makes the header scroll away from the user's view. I'm not sure about some of the styles either; I'm hoping that fixing the positioning issue will clear up some of those issues (: Thanks for your help!

Comment: In that case, simply add margin-top to #content to match the height of #headerSticky. I don't think it is possible to have #content be positioned correctly unless you at least determine the height of #headerSticky.

Comment: I took your advice, and the result was that the extra space (height of headerSticky) was just added on to the very top of the content div, but scrolling down still makes it go behind the header div. Sorry for the complications.

Comment: Try padding-top then?
Also, maybe you could simply add overflow:scroll to #content to make that scroll, if that is the goal.

Answer (score 0):

The property `float:top;` doesn't exist. See here: [w3c Float property](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_class_float.asp).

Position fixed means that this element will always have the same position, when the screen is scrolled, this will "stick" to the place you have positioned it on screen, so when your content is longer than the screen, the header will overlap it, remove this, add a height.

Remove the floats also, these are your basic layout divs and need more accurate positioning than float.

If you could also post up your HTML markup and the CSS for your other element we could probably help you more :)

Hope some of that helps.

Comment: Removing the floats makes the content div stick to the left side of the page; and thus overlaps the side navigation. I did remove the "float:top" and it had no effect; so it definitely wasn't helping. Thanks for the tip! Sorry, which other element's CSS would be helpful?

Comment: If you could post up your HTML, that would make it much easier to suggest some things that would help fix your problem :).

Answer (score 0):

I changed around the CSS a bit and this problem has been solved--here is the code that I used for the header:

```
#headerSticky { 
     height: 28px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 0; 
     width: 100%;
}
```

and the content div:

```
#content {
    height: 100%;
    float:right;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

I know this isn't that different from what I originally had, but I started over from scratch with the CSS and the problem is definitely gone.

Thank you everyone who took the time to answer! I really appreciate it.